# Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Tags: jquery

I have seen similar questions on here, but I haven't resolved my issue yet. I did try moving my CDN link of the Google-hosted jQuery file. I tried three locations for the link - first linked source at the top of the head tag, I also tried to add it right before the closing of the head tag, and also right before the closing of the body tag, but I still am getting Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined in my console. I'm new to jQuery, so any advice would help. I am using a bootstrap theme, and it's sort of a long file, so here's the basics. I have included in my folder js/bjqs.min.js and css/bjqs.css.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>jQuery Practice</title>

    <!--jquery  -->

      <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <!-- Include the plugin *after* the jQuery library -->
<script src="js/bjqs.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS - Uses Bootswatch Flatly Theme: http://bootswatch.com/flatly/ -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="css/freelancer.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/animate.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Include the basic styles -->
<link type="text/css" rel="Stylesheet" href="css/bjqs.css" />

    <!-- Custom Fonts -->
    <link href="font-awesome-4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700,400italic,700italic" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js">

</script>
        <![endif]-->


    </head>


<body>

  <!-- Header -->
    <header>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">

<!--  Outer wrapper for presentation only, this can be anything you like -->
      <div id="banner-fade">

        <!-- start Basic Jquery Slider -->
        <ul class="bjqs">
          <li><img src="img/banner01.jpg" title="Automatically generated caption"></li>
          <li><img src="img/banner02.jpg" title="Automatically generated caption"></li>
          <li><img src="img/banner03.jpg" title="Automatically generated caption"></li>
        </ul>
        <!-- end Basic jQuery Slider -->

      </div>
      <!-- End outer wrapper -->

      <script class="secret-source">
        $(document).ready(function() {

          $('#banner-fade').bjqs({
            height      : 320,
            width       : 620,
            responsive  : true
          });

        });
      </script>




    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Plugin JavaScript -->
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.3/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/classie.js"></script>
    <script src="js/cbpAnimatedHeader.js"></script>

    <!-- Contact Form JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/jqBootstrapValidation.js"></script>
    <script src="js/contact_me.js"></script>

    <!-- Custom Theme JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/freelancer.js"></script>



</body>

</html>
```

Comment: are u sure no problem about your internet conection?

Comment: What protocol are you using to access the page? The leading `//` of the `src` for jQuery assumes the use of `http://` or `https://`.

Comment: Why don't you put the jquery file right before the rest of the javascript files?

Comment: are you loading the page using `file:` protocol... if so you will have to explicitly specify the `http:` protocol when loading resources from internet like `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Did you check your console? is there any 404 error??

Comment: @filoxo if you don't specify the protocol... then the protocol used to load the document that loads the resource is used... so if `file:` protocol was used to load the html page then we have a problem

Comment: @filoxo It is true. This isn't a CDN thing, it's an HTML thing. If you are loading the page locally (from file://) then it's going to try and use that same protocol every time.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I appreciate the responses. Http: fixed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see any issues with your script files. Just make sure that...

- the local script references actually exist in your local dev site
- You have a working internet connection that can access the CDN references
- And make sure you are running this page from a web server instead of loading them from your file system directly

In regards to the last point, if you need to load the page directly from the file system by double-clicking it, you can explicitly set the protocol of the CDN script reference so the browser knows where to go...

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you, yep I did need the http to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case.. if your trying to test your code locally from file:// then the script is not going to load without the protocol being defined..  So you would just need to prefix a http: onto that path.

---

Before running any code that relies on jQuery you could do a check to see if jQuery is loaded and if it is not, load it then; and let you know..

```
if ( typeof jQuery === "undefined" ) {
    console.log('loading jquery..');
    var script_tag = document.createElement ( 'script' );
    script_tag.setAttribute ( "type", "text/javascript" );
    //script_tag.setAttribute ( "src", "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js" ); 
    script_tag.setAttribute ( "src", "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js" );
    script_tag.onload = result;
    script_tag.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if ( this.readyState == 'complete' || this.readyState == 'loaded' ) {
            result();
        }
    };
    document.getElementsByTagName ( "head" )[0].appendChild ( script_tag );
} else {
    result();
}

function result() {
    console.log('ready');
}

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    //your code
});
```

Comment: Thank you, that was it. I needed http:. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

I moved the jQuery link to the top of the jsp page above the lines for bootstrap.min.js and it worked. The order of placement of these below lines are important since the jQuery js needs to be loaded first. I placed the jQuery in the header and bootstrap in the footer so that there is enough time for it to load everything.

```
<script src="jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -3):

yes, you used two jquery script cdn address

```
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.3/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
```

one of them is enough

Comment: Hey @gto999 - there is nothing wrong with using two different CDN addresses. Additionally, this is the type of thing that should really be a comment because it's not an "answer" to the question (aka if the poster does use the same CDN, it isn't going to solve her problem).